# How to get started with mapping the flow of gas pipe network using GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network

I'm looking for some specifications, whitepapers and any other related material about urban gas pipe networks in particular about geometric network rules that are special to gas flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if these links help you out in your search:

[GIS for Gas](http://www.esri.com/industries/gas)

[GIS for Pipeline](http://www.esri.com/industries/pipeline)